# C++ Const Member Function (Beginner)

Tags: c++, member-functions, function-qualifier

In C++ Primer P259, it says

> Objects that are const, and references or pointers to const objects,
>   may call only const member functions.

Based on my current understanding, however, pointers to const objects not necessarily applies because the pointer itself is nonconst. As long as the member function does not modify the object being pointed to, it's legal to call nonconst member functions on pointers to const objects.
Is it correct?

Edit: OK I get it now, it is because when we "call member function on the pointer", we are actually dereferencing it first, and use the object underneath.

Comment: No, it isn't. The quote is correct. I don't know why you believe the const-ness of the pointer to be of any significance.

Comment: `the member function does not modify the object being pointed to`: You mean like a `const` function, or a non-`const` function that just happens to avoid modifying anything?

Comment: "because the pointer itself is nonconst" That means you can change the pointer. Not the thing it points to.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, then for such pointer, why can it only call const member functions?

Comment: Because it is a pointer to const. If you could call non-const members, it wouldn't be a pointer to const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote is correct.

Try this

```
class TestClass
{
public:
  void nonconst(){};

  void constMethod() const {}
};

int main()
{

  TestClass const *s = new TestClass();
  //s->nonconst(); // (1) no not legal
  s->constMethod();

  s = new TestClass(); // (2) yes legal
  s->constMethod();
}
```

1. s is a pointer to a constant. Calling a non const method causes

> passing ‘const TestClass’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

2. However s can point to a different instance. As said in the comments the pointer can be pointed to a different variable.